# Not able to .map a JSON array of objects from Node.js server, but local variable works fine in React

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object

Running a React frontend app with a Node.js backend. Mongodb as the database.

I'm currently experiencing a baffling situation in which I can't map this array "giftingEvents" from my server.

```
{
      "categories": [
        
      ],
      "interests": [
        "rabbits",
        "mansions"
      ],
      "giftingEvents": [
        {
          "eventName": "Birthday",
          "eventDate": "1948-11-01T16:00:00Z"
        },
        {
          "eventName": "Christmas",
          "eventDate": "1948-12-25T16:00:00Z"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "5f1f55630e37e981d401435d",
      "firstName": "Hugh",
      "lastName": "Heffner",
      "age": 97,
      "dateCreated": "2020-07-27T22:29:55.866Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
```

[image]

When I attempt to map the objects in this array from props I receive a typeError

However, I do not receive a typeError when I copy and paste the JSON from my server and use it as a variable in my code.
[image]

Note how I can access the firstName and lastName, from props, but can only access the giftingEvents from a local variable.

Here's what the server output looks like (same as the local variable:
[image]

Here's proof that this array is showing up in my props for Hugh Heffner
[image]

I have tested mapping other arrays that do not contain objects from props IE- "interests", and have had no issues.

```
 "interests": [
        "rabbits",
        "mansions"
      ],
```

Here's where you can see how I've set the props to just a variable "giftedPerson" I have changed this around several times just to try and sanity check myself.
[image]

Here's the entire file of where I try to map from the available props.

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const PersonInfoWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #4d4e5d;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: x-large;
`;

const PersonInfoItem = styled.span`
  padding-left: 7px;
`;


class PersonInfo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    
  }

  render() {

    let giftedPerson = this.props.giftedPerson.giftedPerson

    let giftingEvents = this.props.giftedPerson.giftedPerson.giftingEvents

    let hugh = {
      "categories": [
        
      ],
      "interests": [
        "rabbits",
        "mansions"
      ],
      "giftingEvents": [
        {
          "eventName": "Birthday",
          "eventDate": "1948-11-01T16:00:00Z"
        },
        {
          "eventName": "Christmas",
          "eventDate": "1948-12-25T16:00:00Z"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "5f1f55630e37e981d401435d",
      "firstName": "Hugh",
      "lastName": "Heffner",
      "age": 97,
      "dateCreated": "2020-07-27T22:29:55.866Z",
      "__v": 0
    }

    return (
      <PersonInfoWrapper>
        <PersonInfoItem>Name: {giftedPerson.firstName} {giftedPerson.lastName}</PersonInfoItem>
        {hugh.giftingEvents.map((event, index) => (
              <div key={index} event={event}>{event.eventName}</div>
            ))}
      </PersonInfoWrapper>
    );
  }
}



export default PersonInfo;
```

I know this is likely something extremely simple, but I've been trying to fix this issue for three days :(

Answer (score 0):

For what I can see, you're using a different object that doesn't contain the "giftingEvents" propertie. I can see in your third image, the new object ends in "__v" and starts in "categories", which makes me think it's another property but I can't really tell from here, of course when you use the Hugh Object it will work because it's not inside another object, try this and if that doesn't work, please show us the whole object (if possible) that you're receiving from the props:

```
 {giftedPerson[1].giftingEvents.map((event, index) => (
              <div key={index} event={event}>{event.eventName}</div>
            ))}
```

Comment: If you see the 5th image down, you'll see the exact structure of the server output. 
I just tried to use this code you sent and it still gave me a typeError